# adding attributes to form_open_multipart

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering how could we add attributes to file_upload in codeigniter

right now I am using `form_open_multipart('controller');`

but I want to add an id attribute to it.

Any help appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html):

> form_open_multipart()
>
> This function is absolutely identical
>   to the form_open() tag above except
>   that it adds a multipart attribute,
>   which is necessary if you would like
>   to use the form to upload files with.

So, you would use it in the same way you use `form_open()`. Example:

```
form_open_multipart('controller', 'id="my_id"');
```

Or:

```
form_open_multipart('controller', array('id' => 'my_id'));
```